# python amazon api error connection

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-product-api

I wrote a simple script with the [python amazon api](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/). I copied the example but when I run the script I received the following error:

```
 for book in api.item_search('Books', Publisher='Galileo Press'):
 return paginator(self.call, **operators)   
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amazonproduct/processors/__init__.py",
 line 88, in __init__
 self.page(kwargs.get(self.counter, 1))
 root = self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs) mazonproduct.errors.InvalidClientTokenId: InvalidClientTokenId: The
 AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.   File
 "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amazonproduct/api.py", line
 529, in item_search
 return paginator(self.call, **operators)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amazonproduct/processors/__init__.py",
 line 88, in __init__
 self.page(kwargs.get(self.counter, 1))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amazonproduct/processors/__init__.py",
 line 121, in page
 root = self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amazonproduct/api.py", line
 334, in call
 return self._parse(e.fp)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amazonproduct/api.py", line
 277, in _parse
 raise _e(errors[e.code]) amazonproduct.errors.InvalidClientTokenId: InvalidClientTokenId: The
 AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Go to aws.amazon.com and either create a new account or login to your account. When in the dashboard, click on your name on the menu bar located at the upper right corner of the screen, then select `Security Credentials`. Expand the line item that says `Access Keys (Access Key ID and Secret Access Key)`, and create a new `Access Key ID`. This will also supply you with your `Secret Key`, make sure to record both.

Create a file `~/.amazon-product-api` containing the following data:

```
[Credentials]
access_key = <your access key>
secret_key = <your secret key>
associate_tag = <your associate id>
```

Then your program should run.